# vim setting a default folder to store all txt files, how?

Tags: vim, save, default, directory

I want to set it so that when I write a text file and save it - it is saved to a default folder called TEXT which will be in my main Vim folder eg.
C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73\TEXT

at the moment they are saved by default in the vim73 folder mixed in with everything else.
so if I type :W^M   the file gets saved there and I want it to go to the folder named TEXT

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you save a file vim will default it to your current working directory.  You can use the command `:pwd` to verify this.  To change it you can use `:cd SomeDirectoryPath`.

You could also add the cd command to your .vimrc (or the equivalent for windows) to automatically change your current directory every time you start vim.

Comment: thanks this is what I have done, adding it to my vimrc, works fine

Answer (score 3):

Another possible approach would be to intercept the writing process with an autocmd for a writing event, probably BufWriteCmd.  Have the autocmd function check to see if the file has a .txt extension (or whatever you use) and bypass the normal write process to save however/wherever you want.  For docs see:

```
:h BufWriteCmd
```

Here's some code you could put in vimrc, not thoroughly tested to make sure behavior is exactly what you'd want, but it does basically work:

```
function! WriteTextFile()
    execute 'write! c:\text\'.expand("%:p:t")
    set nomodified
endfunction
au BufWriteCmd *.txt call WriteTextFile()
```

Comment: I have similar autocmds using 'bufwritepost'

Comment: @without:  That would work.  Difference is code I gave saves only in the desired directory.  If this were using BufWritePost then it would save the text files to the desired directory _in addtion_ to the getcwd directory.  I think that's also the case if it were simply in BufWrite, but not positive.

Answer (score 0):

As GWW mentioned, you can add a `cd` command to the _vimrc file. I found the proper format to use difficult to find. The path must not be enclosed in quotes, spaces must be escaped with a backslash, backslashes should not be escaped, and the path must end in a backslash. Here is an example:

```
cd C:\Documents\ and\ Settings\someUser\
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You can use abbrevations, if executed `:w` it's automatically changes to the text below, I think that might help you.

```
cnorea w w! "C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73\TEXT"
```

Comment: @Benoit, I mean the :w save command, not the movemenet command. Your'e right, I've just fixed it.

Comment: still, doing that, you can no more use the following commands: :wn :wall :wq :win :windo :winc :wp. So, I suggest using abbrevs instead of mappings, trigger the abbreviation in command edition only (`c`), and do not trigger other abbreviations (`nore`) with `cnoreabbrev w w! "C:...`

Comment: Is this correct now? Didn't know that a map applies to other commands to. I've fixed it again. Thanks

Comment: I suggest using <expr> abbreviation: `cnoreabbrev <expr> w ((getcmdline()==#'w')?('w! C:\\Program\ Files\\Vim\\vim73\\TEXT'):('w'))`. This will forbid expanding `w` if it is not at the start of the command line. Note that `.../TEXT` is a directory, so you do need something after `TEXT`. Also note that `w! "C:..."` is just the same as `w!` because `"` starts comment. So do not forget to test your answers, -1 for not doing this!

Comment: @ZyX I've tested it, but on a Linux machine. Thus I find your vote not fair. But I've learned something, thus It's ok for me.

Comment: @Farslan are you sure? I tried to use your mapping on an new unnamed empty buffer and it complained about absence of a filename. After seeking the documentation I realized that I cannot find `w "..."` syntax there, so `"` should start a comment. Same for directories: I saved this buffer to `abc` in the current directory and then tried writing to `~/tmp` and it complained about `~/tmp` being a directory (and if you assumed that user must add filename, you should have used Eatchar function and no quotes). I do not know, how you tested this, but your answer does not work.

Comment: You can find Eatchar function by running `helpg Eatchar`.